# A data structure like queue that receives only N per period of time

Tags: java, collections, queue

Is there some data structure in java (standard or in third party library) like blocking queue that can store some tasks and receive only N task per time.
for example:

- N = 3 and period = minute and in queue we have 50 task.
- When I am trying to get first task queue receive them moment of time T1
- When I am trying to get second and third task queue receive them
- When I am trying to get fourth task in moment T2: if (T2 - T1 > minute) then queue receive value; else queue block until (sysdate - T1) will be  more then one minute

Comment: What do you actually try to do? Retrieve at most X items from some collection in a given period of time?

Comment: No. Weird logic like that you have to write yourself. But, try a web search for [`java throttled queue`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+throttled+queue).

Comment: I am trying to prevent situation when in one period of time executed more then N different task. This situation occur when you will try to integrate with external api with limit on function call. For example this external service may have limit maximum 50 call per minute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) :

> An unbounded blocking queue of Delayed elements, in which an element
>   can only be taken when its delay has expired.

Something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final int tasksPerInterval = 3;
    final int totalTasks = 50;
    final int intervalTime = 2;
    final TimeUnit intervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

    DelayQueue<MyRequest> queue = new DelayQueue <>();
    for (int i=0, delayTime=0; i<totalTasks/tasksPerInterval; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<tasksPerInterval; j++){
            queue.offer(new MyRequest<>(i + "-" + j, intervalTimeUnit, delayTime));
        }
        delayTime += intervalTime;
    }

    while (!queue.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(queue.take());

}


static class MyRequest <E> implements Delayed {
    private E data;
    private long startTime;

    MyRequest(E data, TimeUnit timeUnit, long delay) {
        this.data = data;
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(delay, timeUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        long diff = startTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        return unit.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        if (this.startTime < ((MyRequest) o).startTime) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.startTime > ((MyRequest) o).startTime) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data.toString();
    }

}
```

See also the following [question/answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146851/real-world-usage-of-delayqueue).